# Why am I getting duplicate cards per row using bootstrap - react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, react-bootstrap

I could not figure out why I am getting the same card twice per row. This is what I have, following bootstrap's documentation:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Card, Row, Col, Container} from 'react-bootstrap';


function Post({post}) {

console.log("procedure:", post.procedure)
  return (
   
      <div>
        <Row xs={1} md={2} className="row-cols-2" >
     
          {Array.from({ length: 2 }).map((_, idx) => (
            <Col style={{ padding: '3rem' }}>
              <Card border="success" style={{ textAlign: 'center', width: '40rem', padding: '1rem' }} >
                {/* <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px160" /> */}
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>Procedure: {post.procedure}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-primary"><b> Facility: </b> {post.facility.name} - Location:  {post.facility.city}, {post.facility.state}
                  </Card.Subtitle>
                  <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-primary"><b> Patient cost: $</b>{post.patient_cost}</Card.Subtitle>
                  <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-primary"><b> Insurance cost: $</b>{post.insurance_cost}</Card.Subtitle>
                  <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-primary"><b>Date of procedure: </b>{post.date_of_procedure}</Card.Subtitle>
                  <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-primary"><b>Date of invoice: </b>{post.date_of_invoice}</Card.Subtitle>
                  <Card.Text>
                  {post.comments}
                  </Card.Text>
                  <Card.Link as={Link} to={"/average"}><b>Check Average Cost </b></Card.Link>
                  <Card.Link href="#"><b>Another Link </b></Card.Link>
                </Card.Body>
                <Card.Footer>
                  <small className="text-primary"><b>Posted on: </b>{post.created_at}</small>
                </Card.Footer>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      </div>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

I tried adding container, changed the className a few times, and played around with the .map(), but I still get the same card twice per row, instead of 2 different cards per row. Basically, I would like to have 2 cards per row. Not sure what is going on with the grid. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let see if this help you.
With this structure you will have 1 row with 2 cards  for each post.

```
// Parent react component
div.container
// then iterate your posts right?
{
    posts.map((p, i) => {
        return(
            // Here u have 1 post right? use your Post Component
            <Post user={user} setUser={setUser} post={post} key={post.id}/>
        )
    })
}

function Post({post, user, key, setUser}) {
// Here post is a SINGLE ELEMENT right?
    return(
        div.row
        div.col-md-6 // first card - post['some property'] // Maybe here will be the user info
        div.col-md-6 // second card - post['some other property'] // maybe here will be the post info
    )

}
```

Comment: tks, @angelCanales. I tried adjusting the length to 1, but I get 1 column instead of 2. I have 100+ cards that I'd like to display in pairs of 2 per row. I get that with the code I have, but I get the same card twice per row.  If I do not iterate like u mentioned, I also get 1 card per row (same as doing Array.from({ length: 1})).

Comment: ok, just to be clear.. you want 1 row with 2 different card component right?
So, {post} should be an array. Right now you are iterating the same object 2 times.
I will update my answer to be more clear

Comment: I am mapping the posts in another component (where I want it to be rendered), and passing the post to the Post component. This is the .map() I have in the other component: {posts.map(post => <Post user={user} setUser={setUser} post={post} key={post.id}/>)} . Should I transfer the bootstrap card to the component where I have the posts.map() ?

Comment: again I modified my answer, lets see if this time is right :)

Comment: tks,@angelCanales. Not sure I follow what you are instructing me to do. I ll do more researches based in ur answer and see if I can figure it out.